# How to make Access select the entire text in a box instead of all records when using ctrl+a?

Tags: ms-access

In Access, is there a way to set what is selected when a user hits ctrl+a? I have a text box for users to input data, but if they hit ctrl+a, it selects all of the records instead of the entire text of a field. Is there a way to get around this? I am worried about someone accidentally deleting a bunch of records instead of the text of a field.

I'm a beginner user, so please forgive me if I am asking a silly question. I tried to search the forum, but haven't found a good answer.

Comment: You can just have them hit F2 as a trivial workaround: if they have the whole field selected already, it sets the cursor to the beginning or end, but otherwise it selects the whole field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with a textbox and the [Keydown event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834507%28v=office.15%29.aspx), you can say:

```
Private Sub Content_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   ' Debug.Print KeyCode, Shift
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then
        MsgBox "Please use F2"
        KeyCode = 0
        Shift = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

The textbox is called Content in this case.

You may like to get more complicated and look into KeyPreview.